# JAVA SFTP: While overwritting file though JCH. Getting Error "Bad Message"

Tags: java, sftp

I am trying to copy file from one directory to other in SFTP. In the destination directory file is already existing with the same name, i am trying to override it. But when i execute the code i got error message.
Below is the java code

```
public static void main(String a[]) {
      try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession("root", "localhost", 22);
    session.setPassword("root");
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
    channelSftp.cd("/orderstatus");
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = channelSftp.ls("*.txt");
    for(ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : list) {
         System.out.println(entry.getFilename()); 
    }
     channelSftp.rename("test.txt", "/orderstatus/test1/test.txt");

    channelSftp.exit();
    session.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Error I am getting

```
5: Bad message
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.rename(ChannelSftp.java:1950)
at com.rue21.inventory.support.EncryptDecrypt.main(EncryptDecrypt.java:103)
```

I want destination file to be overwritten with source file

Answer (score 1):

1. `ChannelSftp.rename` *moves/renames* the file. It does not *copy* it.
2. You cannot rename/move file over an already existing file. You have to delete the target file before the rename.